# 'In' vs. 'On' followed by a year

Tags: prepositions

I come across a [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_H._W._Bush) where it is written:

> Bush left office **in** 1993.

Is 'In' correct there? Or, maybe, 'On' would be better, 'Bush left office *on* 1993 ...'? Or both are legal English usage?

Comment: In a word, no. "On" is possible only with a specific day. With a year, you must use "in".

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Any time you are being less specific than the day itself, use **“in”** to indicate that the event happened at a time with**in** the boundaries of that century, decade, year, or month.

> **In** the 20th century...
>
> **In** the late '80s...
>
> **In** 1989...
>
> **In** June, 1989

When the day is known, you can say “**On** June 20, 1989...” or “**On** that day in June...”.

When the hour is known, you can say “**At** 3:05 pm on June 20, 1989...”.

For any of these levels, estimates or approximations would be preceded by “**around**” or some similar term. (“**Around** 1990...”, “**At approximately** 3 pm...”, “**At** 3 pm **or so**...”, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Another easier way to remember is:
in a period, on a day, at a time.

while year is a long period, so it is always "in" a year; a time like 7 o'clock is very specific, thus we use "at" all the time.

hope this help.