# Which preposition should I use?

Tags: prepositions

Which one should I use here?

**IN** June 2014

or

**ON** June 2014

Why? Thanks.

Comment: See: http://www.englishclub.com/grammar/prepositions-at-in-on-time.htm

Comment: You would use _in_, but if you added the day, the preposition would change to _on_: ELL opened **in** January 2013; the first ELL question was asked **on** January 23, 2014.

Comment: See my lovely answer [here](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/11041/in-vs-on-followed-by-a-year/11042) as well.